# Sharepoint 2013 - PS to Update Document Library Choice list default value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, powershell, splistitem

I have a library named 'FED'. The library has been in existence for a couple of years. There are some modification needed and this is where it changes:
The 'FED' library has had a new choice field 'Area' added to it. I am looking for some PowerShell script to set the default of area to 'South' and populate all other previously existing items in the list. The below code I am using - is not working. Help would be great.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$web = Get-SPWeb https://mysite
$list = $web.Lists["FED"] 
foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
{ 
  $item["Area"]  = "South"
  $item.Update(); 
}
```

Comment: hi, Please use `$item.SystemUpdate();` and try again

Comment: any errors ? also  in the line `item["Area"]` , you need to use the internal column name, check if you have used correct column name

Comment: I was under pressure to get the job done. My script was throwing errors - so I went for a hack - putting the list into quick edit mode - selecting the choice selection - and copying it to all 315 items. Was desperate. Thanks for your help. Gautam - yes I did have errors. I have no doubt I will look at this again in the future.